# VB.NET Actualizar DataGridView desde otro Form

Tags: vb.net, .net

```
    Public Class FrmMenu

        Private _modelUsuario As New Usuario.Usuario
        Private _controllerUsuario As New ControllerUsuario.ControllerUsuario

        Private _msjAlert As String

        Public Sub New()

            ' This call is required by the designer.
            InitializeComponent()

            ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

        End Sub

        Public Property DaGrViUsuariosProp()
            Get
                Return DaGrViUsuarios.DataSource
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value)
                DaGrViUsuarios.DataSource = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private Sub FrmMenu_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            DaGrViUsuarios.DataSource = _controllerUsuario.RouteGetUsuario(_msjAlert)
        End Sub

        Private Sub BtnAgregarUsuario_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAgregarUsuario.Click
            Dim _frmUsuario As New FrmUsuario
            _frmUsuario.Show()
        End Sub

        Private Sub DaGrViUsuarios_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DaGrViUsuarios.CellDoubleClick
            If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex >= 0 Then
                Dim _frmUsuario As New FrmUsuario
                _frmUsuario.TextUsuarioProp = DaGrViUsuarios.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString
                _frmUsuario.TextNombresProp = DaGrViUsuarios.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString
                _frmUsuario.TextEmailProp = DaGrViUsuarios.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString
                _frmUsuario.TextPasswdProp = DaGrViUsuarios.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString
                _frmUsuario.CmbPerfilProp = DaGrViUsuarios.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value.ToString
                _frmUsuario.Show()
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub BtnRefrescar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnRefrescar.Click
            DaGrViUsuarios.DataSource = _controllerUsuario.RouteGetUsuario(_msjAlert)
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class FrmUsuario

    Private _modelUsuario As New Usuario.Usuario
    Private _controllerUsuario As New ControllerUsuario.ControllerUsuario
    Private _mejAlert As String

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    End Sub

    Public Property TextUsuarioProp()
        Get
            Return TextUsuario.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value)
            TextUsuario.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property TextNombresProp()
        Get
            Return TextNombres.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value)
            TextNombres.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property TextEmailProp()
        Get
            Return TextEmail.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value)
            TextEmail.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property TextPasswdProp()
        Get
            Return TextPasswd.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value)
            TextPasswd.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property CmbPerfilProp()
        Get
            Return CmbPerfil.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value)
            CmbPerfil.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub CargarCampos()
        _modelUsuario.Usuario = TextUsuario.Text
        _modelUsuario.Nombres = TextNombres.Text
        _modelUsuario.Email = TextEmail.Text
        _modelUsuario.Passwd = TextPasswd.Text
        _modelUsuario.Perfil = CmbPerfil.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub FrmUsuario_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnEnviarFormUsuario_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnEnviarFormUsuario.Click
        CargarCampos()
        If _controllerUsuario.Validacion(_modelUsuario, _mejAlert) Then
            _modelUsuario = _controllerUsuario.RouteAddUsuario(TextUsuario.Text, TextNombres.Text, TextEmail.Text, TextPasswd.Text, CmbPerfil.Text)
            MessageBox.Show("Usuario Guardado Exitosamente!.", "Success!")
            Dim _frmMenu As New FrmMenu
            _frmMenu.DaGrViUsuariosProp = _controllerUsuario.RouteGetUsuario(_mejAlert) ' en esta linea deberia actualizar pero no lo hace
            Hide()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(_mejAlert, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

El problema es que al llamar la propiedad publica DaGrViUsuariosProp en el segundo form FrmUsuario no se actualiza la datagridview. La verdad noce que podria esta sucediendo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estas creando una nueva instancia del form cuando deberias usar la existente

```
 Public Class FrmUsuario


    Private _frmMenu As FrmMenu

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(frmMenu As FrmMenu)

        Me.New()

        _frmMenu = frmMenu

    End Sub

    'resto codigo


    Private Sub BtnEnviarFormUsuario_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnEnviarFormUsuario.Click
        CargarCampos()
        If _controllerUsuario.Validacion(_modelUsuario, _mejAlert) Then
            _modelUsuario = _controllerUsuario.RouteAddUsuario(TextUsuario.Text, TextNombres.Text, TextEmail.Text, TextPasswd.Text, CmbPerfil.Text)
            MessageBox.Show("Usuario Guardado Exitosamente!.", "Success!")

            _frmMenu.DaGrViUsuariosProp = _controllerUsuario.RouteGetUsuario(_mejAlert) 

            Hide()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(_mejAlert, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

como veras pasa el form en el constructor y usas esa instancia para acceder al grid

```
Public Class FrmMenu

   'resto codigo

    Private Sub BtnAgregarUsuario_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAgregarUsuario.Click
         Dim _frmUsuario As New FrmUsuario(Me)
        _frmUsuario.Show()
    End Sub

End Class
```

cuando instancia el form le pasas `Me` o sea la instancia de el propio form

Comment: Gracias Leandro, Funciono a la Perfeccion!